# InflateException : Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am able to test my android app on my mobile 5.0 perfectly fine, but testing it on Xiaomi, Asus phones( modified android os phones) throws an exception.

```
Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
```

I tried every solution given to this question on stackoverflow, but the error message still exists.

**actvity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
  android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  tools:openDrawer="start">

  <include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:itemTextColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**build.gradle**

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.image"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 10
    versionName "5.11.10"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**logs**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.image/com.image.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2200)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:623)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:699)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
at com.image.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5245)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052)                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)                                                                         
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:597)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:699) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
at com.image.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5245)                                                                                      
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)                                                                                
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249                                                                                 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)                                                                                
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)                                                                                
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)                                                                              
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)                                                                              
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052)                                                                                
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)                                                                                
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)                                                                              
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)                                                                               
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)      

Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020050                                                                                
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1133)                                                                               
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:285)                                                                             
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)                                                                             
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:190)                                                                              
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:421)                                                                            
at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.prepareMenuItems(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:475)                                                                             
at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.update(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:436)                                                                             
at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:112)
at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateMenu(NavigationView.java:241)
at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:169)                                                                              
at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:95)                                                                               
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)                                                                            
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)                                                                            
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:597)                                                                            
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:699)                                                                            
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)                                                                            
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)                                                                            
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)                                                                       
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)                                                                               
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)                                                                             
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)                                                                           
at com.image.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)                                                                              
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5245)                                                                              
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)                                                                           
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)                                                                              
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249                                                                            
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)                                                                                 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)                                                                               
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)                                                                               
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)                                                                            
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052)                                                                             
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)                                                                              
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)                                                                             
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)                                                                           
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)                                                                              
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i tried all the possible solutions, still i am facing issue only in Xiaomi, Asus phones only.

Comment: can you past your java code too?

Comment: @RajaReddy PolamReddy try to `clean` and `rebuild` it.

Comment: I did all the possible ways.. clean it, rebuild it, and closed multiple times and started again. not working.

Answer (score 0):

check your navigation view by removing one of these and check your code is working or not

```
app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
app:menu="@menu/drawer"
```

if your logcat says cause by resourcenotfoundexception with your above error. issue may be with a icon file/resource file in drawers. if it coming from menu/drawer try changing icons and add icons to drawer folder and to drawer-v21. hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If this is due to proguard or in signed apk then you resove it by adding below line in you proguard-rule file.

```
-keep class org.xmlpull.v1.** { *; }
```